# Haskell pragmas: OPTIONS_GHC vs LANGUAGE

Tags: haskell, language-extension

I find myself using this sort of pragma a lot in my cabal projects to force GHC to build with specific options:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XFlexibleInstances -XRankNTypes ... #-}
```

But when I see other people using extentions, they always declare it in this way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, RankNTypes, ... #-}
```

However, when I load files in GHCi which use the latter method, GHC always complains that I'm using an `unrecognised pragma` and promptly fails.

Why does GHC not accept the `LANGUAGE` pragma, and which of the two is better practice?

---

*Note: my GHC version is up-to-date: 7.8.3, but was 7.6.* when this occurred.*

Comment: Which GHC version? Maybe you have a very old one? Also beware of using a `#` as the very first character of a line when CPP is enabled (in such cases, add a space before that).

Comment: Long shot, but what version of GHC are you running?  (Run `ghc --version` in your shell to find out.)

Comment: Curious. Can you show an entire file that gives this error?

Comment: Make sure that this line is a very first line of a file

Comment: `LANGUAGE` pragmas have worked since 6.8.1. I really think we need a whole file to see what's wrong.

Comment: Notice 7.8.3 is not "100% up-to-date".  There's 7.8.4 and 7.10.1.  Not that any of these versions has issues with LANGUAGE pragma - it sounds like you have a typo in the pragma or other issues.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I searched around my project directory, but I can't seem to find the file in which I first discovered the problem, but now that zudov mentions it, I think I may have declared it _after_ the module name.

Comment: @AJFarmar Hmm. That might not be it. If you put the pragma *after* `module` declaration there would be no error, but GHC would simply consider it as a comment (7.8.4).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the `LANGUAGE` pragma is nicer. Instead of giving a list of arbitrary options it is specific only to language extensions.  It's also designed to be portable between implementations, as mentioned in the GHC docs; `LANGUAGE`

> …allows language extensions to be enabled in a portable way. It is the intention that all Haskell compilers support the `LANGUAGE` pragma with the same syntax, although not all extensions are supported by all compilers, of course. *The `LANGUAGE` pragma should be used instead of `OPTIONS_GHC`, if possible.* [Emphasis added]

This same language shows up in the docs all the way from [GHC 6.6 (§7.10.4)](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.6/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#language-pragma), when `LANGUAGE` was introduced, up through [GHC 7.10.1 (§7.22.1)](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#language-pragma), the current (at time of writing) release.

A third way of specifying language extensions would be to declare them in the cabal file.

I also find that it's common to use `LANGUAGE` pragma to declare used extensions for a single file, but using `OPTIONS_GHC` (on a level of single file) is usually used as a workaround (e.g. to disable some warnings). People prefer to declare GHC options project-wide (with cabal) not on individual files, whereas for some reason language extensions are often used on per-file basis.

Here are a few wild guesses why the `LANGUAGE` pragma might not be recognised:

- You have an ancient GHC version (< 6.6)
- You do not declare it as a *file-header* pragma.
  A file-header pragma must precede the `module` keyword in the file. In other words, it should be at the very top of the file (though it might be preceded by other file-header pragmas)

Comment: If anyone have more guesses why the pragma might be not recognised, please add them to the list (for future generations)

Comment: The reason `LANGUAGE` extensions are often per-file is to ensure that anyone reading the file knows what extensions are in play. It's very good to know whether `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, `OverlappingInstances`, `IncoherentInstances`, `MonoLocalBinds`, `ScopedTypeVariables`, `DataKinds`, and/or `PolyKinds` are in play, and these (at least) may not be entirely obvious from the rest of the source.